# Anchor Link scroll not working correctly when Javascript component included in page

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, anchor

I have a page that is mostly HTML/CSS with one Javascript component in the middle.

I am having an issue with using anchor links to jump to specific parts on the page.
For now I made a section titles Test to test the scrolling behavior.

So when I type in the URL: .../contact#Test it should jump to the Test section.

When I disable Javascript on the page it works as intended.

Also when I go into the CSS and change the Javascript Component's display to none or set a manual height it works as well. But I don't want to set a manual height because the component is dynamic.

But with the component enabled as it is, the page scrolls down to the bottom every time.

[image: screenshot of the page]

Comment: If your component is loading too slow, then the browser will have trouble calculating the correct position to jump to. To work around that, you'll likely have to use JavaScript as well then. If your component fires any sort of "done rendering" event, you could try and tie it to that; otherwise you will have to work with a timeout that gives the component a "reasonable" time to load. You'll need to get/calculate the position of your Test element within the page, and then use a method just as `scrollTo` to go there.

Comment: Or use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView, that spares you from having to calculate the element's position.